# Best practice for handling naturally high coupled classes in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I started using the great SonarQube for continuous inspection of my code. I also love using dependency injection (DI). After analysis, SonarQube tells me that my DI configuration code has high coupling which makes perfect sense. Typically, the class coupling metric reports about 30 where sonar accepts 20. What would be best way to handle this sonar issue? Should i try breaking up the configuration logic into modules to reduce the class coupling? Or is there a simple way to tell sonar that "this is OK" so that the issue will not pop up again in the next analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [flag it as false positive](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Violations+and+Reviews#ViolationsandReviews-FlaggingaViolationasFalse-positive), it should not appear in subsequent analyses.